# Is it possible a many-to-one JOIN with duplicated ids?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables, one is for employees work permits and the other for bosses they were on charge during that permit, bosses tables have unique values related to a certain employee that can have many permits (vacations, medical reasons, etc). Boss table is related to employees by the unique id of the employee and the date they were on charge and the period. I'm struggling joining these tables because apparently I can't do a many-to-one relationship with the two conditions.

```
idemp convert() nameemp
-----------------
1     201801 john
1     201801 john
2     201802 jane

idemp period nameboss
------------------
1     201801 orange
2     201802 pink
3     201802 brown
```

What I'm looking for:

```
idemp convert() nameemp nameboss
-----------------------------
1     201801 john    orange
1     201801 john    orange
2     201802 jane    pink
```

I've tried an outer apply and left join but I keep getting nulls where the id **repeats more than one time** so i'd get something like:

```
idemp convert() nameemp nameboss
-----------------------------
1     201801 john    orange
1     201801 john    NULL
2     201802 jane    pink
```

My code attempts

Outer apply:

```
SELECT     t.idemp, t.period, t.nameemp, d.nameboss
FROM         dbo.employeePermit AS T 
outer apply (select top (1) d.* from bossDot d where D.period= CONVERT(nvarchar(6), T.ORIGINAL_INI, 112) AND D.IDemp = T.IDemp order by d.period asc) d;
--One of the variables are converted in order to join with the period
```

Left outer join:

```
SELECT     t.idemp, t.period, t.nameemp, d.nameboss
FROM         dbo.employeePermit AS T LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.bossDot AS D ON D.period= CONVERT(nvarchar(6), T.ORIGINAL_INI, 112) AND D.IDemp = T.IDemp
--One of the variables are converted in order to join with the period
```

I don't even know if I'm in the right track so any help on the query or approach is appreciated.

[image: Here's how it actually shows results.]

Comment: Your queries posted don't match the columns in your sample. Please post sample data that is relevant to your question.

Comment: Corrected it, the query it's so long that I just cutted most of it to make it look more cleaner in the post. Sorry. @SeanLange

Comment: @Ali . . . Your queries should work.

Comment: I added a picture guys, check the id's are the same but data doesn't fill properly @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my understanding of your question:

You have a table (let's call this table bosses) which has information of the following: 
- boss
- period 
- employee ID
Essentially, this table has the boss-employee relationship.

Then you have another table (let's call this Employee) which has employee information. Now, from the sample data you've posted, I am assuming that there can be multiple records for one employee. (You've posted John twice with the same ID).

And so,that is why the ID repeats in your case when you join. Even if you do an inner join, **the ID will repeat**.

Many to one relationships are possible. Keep in mind, many to one relationships are typically created using primary key-foreign key join. I would try to understand what the primary key is on the Employee table and what the foreign key is on the bosses table. (Keep in mind, a combination of 2-3 columns can be the primary key and if that is the case, use all those columns in your join)
Once you get a thorough understanding of how the relationship is intended between the two tables, try joining them and you should see intended results.

If I haven't answered your question, please feel free to post more data and I can try answering it again.

Comment: You actually cleared my idea better, I don't have relationships because many of these tables that I work on get deleted after I generate a report. Thanks and welcome!.

Comment: Glad I could help :-) Good luck

Comment: Added a relationship on the employee ID, joined both tables again and I got my results correctly displayed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A `LEFT JOIN` will work in your case. Please find the query with the sample data:

```
DECLARE @WorkPermits TABLE (idemp INT, [period] VARCHAR(6), nameemp VARCHAR (10));

INSERT INTO @WorkPermits (idemp, [period], nameemp) VALUES 
(1, '201801', 'john'),
(1, '201801', 'john'),
(2, '201802', 'jane');

DECLARE @Bosses TABLE (idemp INT, [period] VARCHAR(6), nameboss VARCHAR (10));

INSERT INTO @Bosses (idemp, [period], nameboss) VALUES 
(1, '201801', 'orange'),
(2, '201802', 'pink'),
(3, '201802', 'brown');

SELECT W.idemp, W.period, W.nameemp, B.nameboss
FROM @WorkPermits AS W 
LEFT JOIN @Bosses AS B ON B.idemp = W.idemp;
```

Output:

```
idemp   period  nameemp nameboss
---------------------------------
1      201801   john    orange
1      201801   john    orange
2      201802   jane    pink
```

You may modify the query with your actual table and column names.

Comment: Thank you, but LEFT JOIN doesn't work either (I uploaded a new picture to the post).